# Generate JSON file from Xcdatamodel

Tags: ios, json, xcode, xcdatamodel

Is it possible to generate **JSON** file from **xcdatamodel**?

Here's how I imagine it would work: Given a ***xcdatamodel*** file, going through some program with some custom logic (will probably be written by me), will generate ***JSON*** file for me to use in *third-party library*. My question: Is this possible? Has anyone ever done it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Ok, proof it if you can

Answer (score 0):

The content of **xcdatamodel** is a `content` file with ***xml*** data and as **bin** file (no extension) so now it is easy to parse `xml` to `json`.